# How to create a query that shows all different row data when joining with a link table?

Tags: mysql, join

Currently I am trying to create a HTML table that shows all users and if that user downloaded a certain file.

### Tables

One for the users:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

One for the files:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `file_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And a link table to save what file is downloaded by which user:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `downloads` (
  `download_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`download_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### Query

When I select file_id 3 I want to see every user and if they have the file downloaded or not.

```
SELECT `file_id`, `user_name`, IF(`file_id` = '3', 1, 0) as `downloaded`
FROM `users` 
NATURAL RIGHT JOIN `downloads`
WHERE `file_id` = '3'
GROUP BY `user_name`
```

### Result

Output should be something like:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| file_id  | user_name     | downloaded  |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| 3        | John          | 1           |
| 3        | Peter         | 1           |
| 3        | Jack          | 0           |
| 3        | Michael       | 0           |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Could anyone help me? Or point me in the right direction?

Test area: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f81/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT 3 file_id, user_name, IF(d.file_id = 3, 1, 0) downloaded 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN downloads d ON d.user_id = u.user_id && d.file_id = 3
ORDER BY downloaded DESC
```